# Как оформить реплики в диалоге строкой, если они выборочны, то есть непоследовательны?

Tags: пунктуация, тире, кавычки, прямая-речь, многоточие

Есть правило, что если несколько реплик следует в строку без указания, кому они принадлежат, то каждая из них выделяется кавычками и, кроме того, отделяется от соседней посредством тире. Однако как оформить реплики, которые идут в диалоге выборочно, то есть не подряд? Возможно, в начале и/или конце каждой из них нужно поставить многоточие, чтобы показать, что до и после неё пропущены фразы? Как быть, есть такие примеры в литературе?

*Издали только и слышалась их ругань. "Ты виноват, сколько можно?!" — "Зачем флягу выбросила?" — "Иди ты, не было в сумке никакого хлеба!" — "Это вообще Денис сломал". И не было ей конца...*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Издали только и слышалась их ругань. "Ты виноват, сколько можно?!", "Зачем флягу выбросила?", "Иди ты, не было в сумке никакого хлеба!", "Это вообще Денис сломал". И не было ей конца...**

Поскольку реплики не связаны в диалог, то их вполне можно оформить через запятую, то есть как перечисление, как примеры.